# How to run SRT server on local?

Tags: c, server, streaming

I want to create a streaming application which is responsible for send and receive live audio/video stream.
But this audio/video stream must be equipped with FEC client server error mechanism. I have done some R&D and found that Haivision has provided open source SRT solution.
I have setup project as suggested here https://github.com/Haivision/srt but no idea how to run this server.
Please guide me how can i start this server. Reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The SRT library is provided with API guides to allow you build it into your own applications and 'hubs', rather than a ready to go 'server' that you configure and run.

The API includes information on how to 'start' SRT and on how to set up a socket to listen for traffic - e.g.:

> Setup and teardown
>
> Before any part of the SRT C API can be used, the user should call srt_startup() function. Likewise, before the application exits, the srt_cleanup() function should be called. Note that one of the things the startup function does is to create a new thread, so choose the point of execution for these functions carefully.

**SRT Usage - listener (server)**

```js
sockaddr_in sa = { ... }; // set local listening port and possibly interface's IP
    int st = srt_bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof sa);
    srt_listen(sock, 5);
    while ( !finish ) {
       socklen_t sa_len = sizeof sa;
       newsocket = srt_accept(sock, (sockaddr*)&sa, &sa_len);
       HandleNewClient(newsocket, sa);
    }
```

The info is all in the API section of the link you highlighted: https://github.com/Haivision/srt/blob/master/docs/API.md

There is (at the time of writing) a guide to using the SRT library with ffmpeg to send and receive data - this may be what you are looking for: https://medium.com/@eyevinntechnology/using-ffmpeg-and-srt-to-transport-video-signal-to-the-cloud-7160960f846a